# MAX aggregate function in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I wrote the following query to return the the records with the latest date.

```
select fs.company_id, max(fs.create_dt) as latestcreatedate
from field_sale fs 
group by fs.company_id
order by fs.company_id
```

The query all works fine. But I need to retrieve the record with all related columns attached to it. Such as, id, title, desc and etc.

How can I retrieve the records with its corresponding columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways of doing so :

```
-- 1. 
SELECT a.* 
FROM field_sale a 
INNER JOIN 
(
select fs.company_id, max(fs.create_dt) as latestcreatedate
from field_sale fs 
group by fs.company_id   
)b 
ON b.company_id = a.company_id AND b.latestcreatedate = a.create_dt
order by a.company_id;

--  2.  
SELECT b.* FROM 
( 
   SELECT a.* , ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY a.company_id ORDER BY a.create_dt DESC)
    AS rn
   FROM field_sale a 
)b WHERE b.rn  = 1
ORDER BY company_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    t AS (
           SELECT   fs.company_id,
                    fs.create_dt AS latestcreatedate,
                    id,
                    title,
                    etc,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY fs.company_id ORDER BY fs.create_dt DESC ) AS rowNum
           FROM     field_sale fs
         )
SELECT  t.company_id,
        t.latestcreatedate,
        t.id,
        t.title,
        t.etc
FROM    t
WHERE   t.rowNum = 1
ORDER BY t.company_id
```